# What is wrong with this Oracle SELECT command?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

when I run this query:

```
(SELECT MAX(
  SELECT 
    COUNT(e4.employee_id) 
  FROM 
    employees e4, 
    departments d2 
  WHERE 
    d2.manager_id = e3.employee_id AND
    e4.department_id = d2.department_id
  ) 
FROM 
  employees e3
)
```

I got an ORA-00936: missing expression. I don't know where is mistake.

Comment: Ummmm.....the subquery returns one number, hence rendering the outer `max()` query superfluous.

Comment: The inner SELECT has a COUNT but no GROUP BY...

Comment: @RobbieDee they don't need a group by, there's only one field and it has a function.

Comment: I added outer SELECT MAX(...) query because i need to inspect each e3 employee within inner query that counts employees those meets condition in WHERE block. Can inner query see outer e3 symbol?

Comment: Can you explain what this query is trying to achieve? It looks like what is here is equivalent to `Select Max(dept_size) From (Select department_id, count(*) as dept_size From employees group by department_id) as a`. But the way your query is written looks like you mean something else.

Comment: @BorkoDjurovic - No, you don't understand. The inner query returns one number. That's it: one row, one column. One stinking number. When you take the maximum of one number, guess what you get? <cue Jeopardy theme>

Answer (score 1):

My friend told me how to change this query. My query is trying to return maximum number of employees that one manager have.

I'm new in SQL and I'm writing long queries :)
The correct one is:

```
SELECT
    MAX(counter)
FROM
(SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM
    employees e
    GROUP BY
    e.manager_id)
```

Comment: This solution is more complex than it needs to be. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

```
SELECT
    MAX(COUNT(*))
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY
    manager_id
```